# Putting a middleware in Node js + Express

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I have this different files for my rest api in node js with express

1. app.js
2. router.js
3. controller.js

app.js

```
var routes = require('./source/router');
.......
app.use('/application', routes);
```

router.js

```
var express = require('express');
var controller= require('./controller');
var router = express.Router();
router.route('/register').post(controller.register);
```

controller.js

```
module.exports = {
   register : function(req,res){
   }
}
```

It works perfectly but i want to put a middleware only in the endpoint of register. I have tried different ways but none was working. I want to mantain this structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wanting to keep the same structure limits your options, but try doing this:

```
function customMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  //your code
    next();
}

router.route('/register').post(customMiddleware, controller.registerHero);
```

Comment: Why exactly do you expect `if (err) throw err;` to do?

Comment: @jfriend00 do you mean what* do i expect it to do?

Comment: Well, it won't do anything useful.  It should probably call `next(err)`.  You don't just randomly `throw` in the middle of a route handler.  Lots of people seem to think that `if (err) throw err;` is somehow useful in server development.  It's almost never the right thing unless the code is synchronous and you've specifically defined an exception handler to handle that exception.

Comment: can you please mark the answer as correct @AvedisMaroukian

Comment: There I put it !

Comment: I dont know how but know the middleware is not being called.

Comment: I have to quit the parameter error from the middleware.

Comment: If I put it like this customMiddleware(err, req, res, next) it was never getting to the function of the middleware, I remove "err" from the inputs and it worked.

Comment: @AvedisMaroukian oh i see! Great. I’ll update the answer. Good job!